# JBOSS dependencies for project using maven

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, jboss, jboss5.x

This should be simple but can't figure it out. I have a web project that is built using Maven and will be deployed on a JBOSS-EAP 5.1 server. What do I add to my pom.xml so that Maven has access to the JBOSS EAP libraries at build time?

Is there a particular dependency or plugin I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is a feature for EAP 6, and experimental even at that. See more information from [here](https://sso.jboss.org/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fissues.jboss.org%2Fbrowse%2FJBPAPP-1935%3F_sscc%3Dt&gateway=true) and [here](http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/03/20/jboss-enterprise-maven-repository-available-with-the-enterprise-application-platform-6-beta/):

> A magnificent enhancement to the previous version is, that the EAP 6
>   ships with a Maven repository, which includes all EAP-related Maven
>   artifacts. The missing maven repository was a big disadvantage of
>   previous EAP versions. The required Maven artifacts had to be manually
>   deployed from the EAP distribution into your own local Maven
>   repository or into your enterprise Maven repository like Nexus or
>   Artifactory.

So no, I don't think such repository exists for Jboss EAP 5.X.

This means that in practice you have the following choices, from most recommended to the least:

- Have an intranet repo, such as Nexus or Artifactory, and install the items there. Then you can refer to them as dependencies from your pom. This option is recommended.
- Install them locally only into each developers local maven repo. You would use mvn install-file for this, and each developer would need to do this by themselves. After that, each dependency could be referenced from pom in the way other dependencies are.
- Use system scope on your pom, pointing directly to the libraries stored somewhere on your hard drive. This would be a fragile setup, easy to break.

It shouldn't be too hard to just store the libraries on your intranet repository and use that. Having an intranet repo for developers is a best practice you should be using anyway.

Comment: See what I did above. Just used a generic Java EE dependency as opposed to a specific JBOSS one. Your answer was closest to answering what I asked so have marked it as accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, using just a generic JEE dependency is the recommended way, and only using JBoss-specifics if absolutely neccessary. I had the same recommendation in my answer, but changed it due to not really fitting what was asked. Glad it worked out that way :)

Answer (score 3):

Considering JBoss is an EE container, adding the JavaEE dependency should be enough.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Scope provided ensures that JBoss's own libraries are used once the application is deployed to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first identify what exactly are your projects dependencies and add them as dependencies in your `pom.xml`. Now identity what all are available with jboss and make the scope of those dependencies as `<scope>provided</scope>` so that it is not bundled with `war`. During build time maven will have to take the jars from maven repository.

Comment: that's the good (manual) way, but it could be easier to define all the JBoss dependencies as provided scope with just one dependency like org.jboss.as:jboss-eap:5.1.0.GA:pom (and its related dependencies) in a provided scope : so nobody has done that work ?

Answer (score 1):

Jboss packages are available now (and have been for some years) at

```xml
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-repository</id>
            <name>JBoss Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

(*Below is the answer that the OP [erroneously included in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12404259/2)*)

What I did in the end was add the following dependency to my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.j2ee</groupId>
        <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Not a direct answer to what I asked (I asked specifically about JBOSS) but it gives me all the Java EE APIs I need to compile. I can't running anything using this as it doesn't implement any of the APIs - this is provided by my Java EE app server (JBOSS in this instance).