# Eclipse maven jboss project - what do I need to add to the pom.xml so maven can compile?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss, m2eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I managed to set up my Jboss WTP project in maven. Right click on the project > Run as > Run on server (Jboss 7) works fine. But if I go ahead and delete the `target` directory and then try to execute `compile` goal it fails with missing dependencies:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.\
singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PROJECT 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ PROJECT ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\path\\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ PROJECT ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\path\\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/path/to/file/Controller.java:[14,21] package javax.servlet does not exist
#..... NOTICE THIS COMES FROM A CUSTOM JAR
[ERROR] /C:/path/to/file/DataServlet.java:[3,30] package gr.uoa.di.java.helpers does not exist
#.....
[ERROR] /C:/path/to/file/DataServlet.java:[26,32] package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/path/to/file/DataServlet.java:[28,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
#.....
[INFO] 49 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I clean the project so the target directory is populated with classes then try to compile the project all fine:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ DataCollectionServlet ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
```

I have 1 question:

- What exactly should I add to the `pom.xml` to *reproduce the compilation environment of the `Run on Server` eclipse command* ? **EDIT**: For instance [adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404259/jboss-dependencies-for-project-using-maven):

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```

  to the pom solved the "servlet API not found" issue - but is it the way to go ? Or should I add [something like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498032/adding-jboss-as-7-modules-on-eclipse-using-maven-or-jboss-tools):

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-as-spec-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

  (see [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.as/jboss-as-spec-api/7.1.1.Final)). **NB**: adding the dependencies suggested by m2e plugin would result in a huge pom - moreover I am not sure all of it would be needed (it's a plain servlet/jsp project):

  [image]

I am on  Eclipse Luna Java EE pack, maven 3.1 (the one that comes with eclipse) and using Jboss 7.1.1.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This transitively added the servlet-api:

[image]

Still don't know if adding this is the right way to add jstl 1.2.1 - notice it adds the jstl **1.2** api (EDIT: it isn't: [Standard way of adding JSLT 1.2.1 in a Maven Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262223/standard-way-of-adding-jslt-1-2-1-in-a-maven-project/24468573#24468573))

I also still have problems with my homebrew jar ([Can maven treat WEB-INF\lib the way eclipse (and m2e) does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287093/can-maven-treat-web-inf-lib-the-way-eclipse-and-m2e-does)) but closing this for now.